# XMLHttpRequest returns response "undefined" with status 0 in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, soap, xmlhttprequest

I am sending a request to EJBCA web service. Please see my code below. I am getting `undefined` as a response and the status being printed is 0.

```
let XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = 0;
const fs = require('fs');

let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open('POST', 'https://104.211.18.242/ejbca/ejbcaws/ejbcaws', true, 'ejbcaadmin', 'iBOTControls@123');

var strRequest = `
    <x:Envelope
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ws="http://ws.protocol.core.ejbca.org/">
    <x:Header/>
    <x:Body>
        <ws:getAvailableCAs></ws:getAvailableCAs>
    </x:Body>
    </x:Envelope>
    `;

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-client-key, x-client-token, x-client-secret, Authorization');


//send the SOAP request
xmlhttp.send(strRequest);

//Callback function for response
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    console.log(xmlhttp.response) // returns undefined
    console.log(xmlhttp.status) // prints 0
    fs.writeFileSync('./response.txt', xmlhttp.responseXML)
}
```

Sending a request to this web service needs https client authentication. When I send a request through browser, I have to select a certificate and then I receive 200 response. Since I am not attaching the certificate in node.js, could it be failing?

Comment: Why are you setting Access-Control headers? They are **response** headers and have no place on the request … and they only apply to browsers anyway.

Comment: Why bother? Use a library like Axios. `const response = await axios.post(url, strRequest)`, job done

Comment: @JeremyThille I used axios like this                                                                           ```let instance = axios.create({
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
    }
});

instance.post('https://104.211.18.242/ejbca/ejbcaws/ejbcaws', strRequest)
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data)
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e)
    })```                                                                                                                                      getting socket hang up error with code econnreset

Comment: Yes, I just tried calling the API with Postman, it hangs. I also get `socket hang up`. I think it's broken/offline.

Comment: Is it because https client authentication is not provided in the request. A client certificate is needed to access the api through the browser and the api works. But I dont know how to pass is through node.js